# Quicksort Invariant and steps to determine correcteness

Tags: java, beginner, sorting, quick-sort

I am having trouble with applying to 3 steps needed to proof correctness, most likely because I did not formally study CS or Mathematics and am still learning about loop and class invariants. The three steps:

1. Initialization
2. Maintenance
3. Termination

My understanding of the invariant is that, at the end of the partitioning process, we will have split the array into 3 regions. One where all elements are less than pivot, the pivot itself, and the region where all elements are larger or equal to the pivot.

Assuming the invariant I stated above is correct, I do not see how it is true before, and after the each iteration (which I believe is a requirement for correctness)

```
private static void sort (Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi){
    
    // a has been shuffled using fisher-yates-knuth

    if (hi <= lo)
        return;

    // pivot is chosen, a[j],  rearranges a[lo:hi], such that all elements  a[lo:j-1] are less than pivot a[j] and all elements a[j+1:hi] are greater than pivot
    int partitionIndex = partition(a, lo, hi);

    sort(a, lo, partitionIndex - 1);
    sort(a, partitionIndex + 1, hi);


}

/**
 *
 * @param a array to sort
 * @param lo start index of segment that needs to be partitioned
 * @param hi end index of segment that needs to be partitioned
 * @return index of the pivot
 */
private static int partition(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi){
    // arbitrarily choose pivot
    Comparable pivot = a[hi];

    int partitionIndex = lo;

    // scan array from lo to hi - 1, we skip hi because this is the pivot element

    // iterate over elements lo to hi - 1, since hi is already pivot there is no need
    for (int i = lo; i < hi; i ++){
        if (isLessThan(a[i], pivot)){
            exchange(a, i, partitionIndex);
            partitionIndex++;
        }
    }
    exchange(a, hi, partitionIndex);



    // at this point, our array should be partitioned (divided) in three regions

    // region 1: pivot should be greater than all elements to its left
    // region 2: pivot should be less than or equal to all elements to its right
    // region 3: pivot was placed in the middle of the partition (the two regions)
    assert leftRegionCorrect(a, lo, partitionIndex) && rightRegionCorrect(a, lo, partitionIndex) && a[partitionIndex] == pivot;


    return partitionIndex;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The invariant you stated is correct. These invariants hold for the partition loop, so they should hold before partition and after partition.

Before partition, we have to consider the pivot to be the largest element for our data type (`Integer.MAX_VALUE` in java). We can do this, because the pivot does not need to be part of the array. The three regions are: region 1, the entire array, as every element there is smaller by definition than our pivot. region 2 is the empty array, region 3 is the empty array, as no element is larger than our pivot. These respect the invariant.

The first thing we do for our partition is we chose a random pivot again. Now we are already in the loop, so it does not matter that the pivot is not at its right place yet.

After the partition, we end with our pivot in the middle. This time, we no longer have empty region 2 and region 3.

Now we are again before the loop of our partition, but this time we have smaller arrays. We know the largest element of the left sub-array (our old pivot), so that suffices as the initial pivot. The right sub-array will have our first pivot, the maximum possible value. And then we reiterate.

Probably the most non-intuitive part is that the pivot initially doesn't have to be part of the array, and can be the largest possible value for the datatype. This won't help you in practice when writing code, but it does help you see how the theory is correct (and how to check your programs). You don't have to write anything extra, you don't even have to ever use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in this program. You may have been confused by thinking that the `for` statement is the actual loop. That loop has its own invariants, but they are for another time.

Also, another general advice is that usually loop invariants, to be useful, depend on the loop variable. In the case of the `for`, it should depend on the `i` and `partitionIndex`.